# How to tell when Sendgrid's DeliverAsync is done (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, pdf-generation, sendgrid

I'm working with Sendgrid to send out emails Async (in vb.net) and want to notify the user when the process is complete. What's the fastest/easiest way to do this? I'm still new to threads and don't know how to wait on a sendgrid task/thread to finish.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `Await` keyword, to cause the cause execution to stop until the message has been sent to SendGrid:

```
Dim response = Await YourAsyncDeliveryFunction(email)
' Do what you want
```

*However*, sending a message to SendGrid does not mean that it's in the user's inbox. The email still needs to be processed by SendGrid, sent to the user's email service provider, which in turn needs to process it and provide *that* to the user. So, it's near impossible to tell a user when an email is actually in their inbox. *Most people just opt to tell users that they should receive an email shortly.*

Comment: Thanks so much! Yeah I realise once it's with Sendgrid that's up to their servers.